# Loading wordpress footer image from featured image on post

Tags: wordpress

I've taken over a wordpress site from a previous developer, which was designed using a custom theme but is unfinished.

The objective is to get a different image within the footer of each page, followed by some footer text that is the same on every page. The image is specific to that page.

At the moment, it is set up so every page of the website uses a different template, each of which calls a footer specific to that page, so there are around 30 different footer files.

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this! I've played with putting the image in the page, but this will only span the full width if using a no sidebar template.

Is there a way to do it if I switch all the pages to posts instead, then use the featured image on the post editing page? Unsure how to call that in the footer, but I'm sure there's a way!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use CMB2 (or Advanced custom fields if you prefer GUI over coding) to add your custom image field to pages and display that field in footer.

It cannot get much simpler than that... ;-)

Comment: I'm struggling with how to display that field in the footer?

Comment: I'll start a new question that's more specific, now I've figured out half of it...